# compiler doesn't seem to find a member function of class llvm::Instruction

Tags: llvm

I am very new to llvm code and I am trying to escape an instruction if it met some conditions. What I am trying to do for escape is using the `Instruction::getNextNonDebugInstruction()` function which gives me this error when I compile:

> ‘class llvm::Instruction’ has no member named
>   ‘getNextNonDebugInstruction’;

It doesn't make sense since we can see that `getNextNonDebugInstruction()` is a public and present member in Instruction class:

https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ae7b05782d5230743f5dda7825f0ebd88

Here is my code:

```
llvm::Instruction* inst_ = ki->inst;

if(isa<CallInst>(inst_) && str.find("bpf")!= std::string::npos)
      {
        llvm::Instruction* next_inst = inst_->getNextNonDebugInstruction();

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function was added to the LLVM codebase about a year ago (see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/f01827f2d1bdaff14cf1cf176e8a69e308d5371e ). It sounds like your version doesn't include that change.